# Majority logic decoding Haskell

Tags: haskell, logic, decoding

I have to calculate the probability of the proper decoding of a bit copied `n` times.
The following formula is supposed to be the answer:

[image: the formula]

In Haskell, I coded it as follows:

```
fac 1 = 1
fac n = fac (n-1) * n
--prob :: (Integral b, Fractional b) => (b, b) -> b
--prob :: (Int,Int) -> Double
prob (n, k)
    | n==k = (0.01**k)
    | otherwise = factor (n, k) * (0.01 ** k) * (0.99**(n-k)) + prob (n, (k+1)) 
    where
        factor (n, k) = (fac n / ((fac k)* (fac n-k)))
```

`1 - prob (3,2)` gives the result `0.99992575`, which is incorrect, as it should be `0.99970`. Does anyone know where I went wrong?

Comment: Make the epsilon a parameter to `prob`, and I personally would make a wrapper around it that calculates `k` for me from the `n` passed in.  Adjust the epsilon to be smaller and see if that's what the problem is.

Comment: why would you comment out the type?

Comment: this looks too much like newtons binom formula

Comment: @user3329719 They're very related: This formula calculates the probability of `(n+1)/2` or more errors using a [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

Answer (score 6):

The reason is function precedence.
if you would look into the definition of prob you will see this:

```
(fac n-k)
```

because function application has the most precedence this is parsed as

```
((fac n) - k)
```

so your code should be

```
(fac (n-k))
```

which gives a result of 0.999702 on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

These are a couple of best-practices the code is lacking. I infact already answered the question itself.

1- do not use tuples as input. in Haskell, functions can have multiple parameters. the syntax is `f x y` for calling `f` on `x` and `y`. the types also have similar syntax. this transforms your code to:

```
fac 1 = 1
fac n = fac (n-1) * n
--prob :: (Integral b, Fractional b) => b -> b -> b (two parameters of type b and output of type b)
--prob :: Int -> Int -> Double
prob n k
    | n==k = (0.01**k)
    | otherwise = factor n k * (0.01 ** k) * (0.99**(n-k)) + prob n (k+1) 
    where
        factor n k = (fac n / ((fac k)* (fac (n-k))))
```

2- if you will notice, `fac` will only work on Integers, and similarly does `factor`. prob infact then has type of `(Fractional a, Integral b) -> b -> b -> a` or alternatively `Integer -> Integer -> Float`. why not give them their *true* type?

this transformation requires changing `**` (which gets two floating point numbers) to `^` (which gets an Integer as it's second parameter) and using the function `fromIntegral` which casts an Integer to an arbitrary number Data.

```
fac :: Integral a => a -> a -- or alternatively Integer -> Integer
fac 1 = 1
fac n = fac (n-1) * n
prob n k
    | n==k = (0.01 ^^ k)
    | otherwise = fromIntegral (factor n k) * (0.01 ^^ k) * (0.99 ^^ (n-k) + prob n (k+1) 
    where
        factor n k = div (fac n) (fac k * fac (n-k)) -- div is Integer division operator.
```

now `prob` has type of `(Integral a, Floating b) => a -> a -> b` which means it gets two parameters of type `a` (which is an Integral instance) and returns a value of type `b`.